# what is the best alternative to Java's TTS( text to speech) API?

Tags: java, android

I am working on this side project and one part of the project is converting text to speech. currently I am using the free TTS java api and it works fins. but I am not happy with the voice.

so, my question is,

1. is there a way to change just the voice into a bit human like voice?
2. if not what is the best alternative?

   I am using android studio IDE if that helps.

Thank you in advance...!

Comment: Either the end user can [install other voices](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.acapelagroup.android.tts) or you can [integrate an alternative TTS library in your app](https://www.acapela-group.com/solutions/acapela-tts-for-android/).

Answer (score 1):

Best bet is to use a service https://cloud.google.com/text-to-speech/ one the best ones out there as it's developed by possibly hundreds of the top developers.